# Angularjs - How to store the response received from $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json file. I want to get the data from that file using `$http.get` and store that in variable so that I can use it later in the controller. Something like this:

```
$http.get('items.json').success(function(response){
    var data = response;    //data can't be used outside this function
})
```

I want to use `data` outside the function.

Comment: You can declare variable outside the function

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the below fashion:

```
var data;
$http.get('items.json').success(function(response){
    data = response;    //data can't be used outside this function
})
```

here data now will be accissible to all the methods of your controller.

**But my suggestion is to make one angular service and put $http code inside it. And then inject this service
inside your controller and use it.**

Below would be the code:

### Service Code:

```
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
  this.getData = function(successHandler, failureHandler) {
    $http.get('items.json').then(function(response){
      successHandler(response);    //data can't be used outside this function
    }, function(response) {
      failureHandler(response);
    })

  }
});
```

### Controller Code:

```
app.controller('MyCntrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  var data;

  function successHandler(res) {
    data = res;
  }

  function failureHandler(res) {
    data = res;
  }

  $scope.getData = function() {
    MyService.getData(successHandler, failureHandler);
  }

});
```

The above solution would help you to separate out the concerns related to service and controller and to make your application
more modular and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create data outside that function. like

```
var data;
$http.get('items.json').success(function(response){
    data = response;    //data can't be used outside this function
});
```

But in this way also data will be undefined unless get call gives response, evenif you are using JSONP from local. 
Ideal way to do this is using promises. as below

```
var callService = function(){
 return $http.get('items.json').success(function(response){
        return response; // Response variable will be input to promise
    });        
};
callService.then(function(data){
// this data variable will be equal to response.
});
```

Further reading on 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Why start a new promise, when the $http promise already returned?

Comment: Yes agree. you can return that itself, as promises can be channed.I have modified my answer

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. use `then`

Answer (score 0):

dont create a variable inside call, declare that variable outside and just assign value for it.

```
var data;
$http.get('items.json').success(function(response){
    data = response;    //data can't be used outside this function
});
```

Comment: I did this. But `console.log(data)`; gives `undefined`

Comment: i hope you have gave console immediately after you completed  get method, it is internet call it will take some time to get response

Comment: You have to make sure your promise resolved successfully. Where did you put your `console.log(data)`? Please note that the legacy promise handlers `success` and `error` are deprecated. Use `then` instead.

Comment: to check it assign value to scope variable and in template view its value, using {{variableName}} . value will change once it got that data

Answer (score 0):

as all mentionned create the variable outside the function. 
BUT USE `THEN` instead of `success` because it is depreceted

> Deprecation Notice
>
> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

`var data;
   $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/someUrl'
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
     console.log(reponse); // response contain status , data, headers, config...
     data = response.data ;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });`